# Neo4j DB change from version 3.0.5 to 3.1.1

Tags: neo4j

I have a DB of neo4j which is in Neo4j 3.0.5 version and my friend is having Neo4j version 3.1.1, I gave him a graph.db folder of neo4j so that he can use my DB.

Now he is having a problem importing it. Can Anyone suggest me for porting from version 3.0.5 to 3.1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your friend should enable the following line in the .conf file:

```
# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
dbms.allow_format_migration=true
```

Comment: That's the way. Here's the [relevant upgrade steps](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.1/upgrade/deployment-upgrading/#upgrade-instructions-3x) from 3.x to 3.1.x, but the above is the key here.